# Default value of read_only_fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

There is a Django Rest API project. There is a `FooSerializer` which extends `serializers.ModelSerializer`:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = DEFAULT_FOO_FIELDS + ['foo']
        read_only_fields = []
```

Does the `read_only_fields` has to be set empty list every time or the empty list is the default value and the expression can be just ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field doesn't exist until you configure it. So, the method that implements the functionality resolves to None. Here's the implementation of one of the method from ModelSerializer class, responsible for extracting meta information:

```
 def get_extra_kwargs(self):
        """
        Return a dictionary mapping field names to a dictionary of
        additional keyword arguments.
        """
        extra_kwargs = copy.deepcopy(getattr(self.Meta, 'extra_kwargs', {}))

        read_only_fields = getattr(self.Meta, 'read_only_fields', None)
        if read_only_fields is not None:
            if not isinstance(read_only_fields, (list, tuple)):
                raise TypeError(
                    'The `read_only_fields` option must be a list or tuple. '
                    'Got %s.' % type(read_only_fields).__name__
                )
            for field_name in read_only_fields:
                kwargs = extra_kwargs.get(field_name, {})
                kwargs['read_only'] = True
                extra_kwargs[field_name] = kwargs

        else:
            # Guard against the possible misspelling `readonly_fields` (used
            # by the Django admin and others).
            assert not hasattr(self.Meta, 'readonly_fields'), (
                'Serializer `%s.%s` has field `readonly_fields`; '
                'the correct spelling for the option is `read_only_fields`.' %
                (self.__class__.__module__, self.__class__.__name__)
            )

        return extra_kwargs
```

Comment: That is a nice detailed answer, that clarifies things for me.